# Android's font doesnt show content in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, scrollview

As we all know, you can customize the font size of your android phone. When a user has the font in large or huge (the common one to use is "normal") and they reach an specific fragment (that has a button), the whole content of the fragment is not shown in screen, the font being so big, moves the text from 2 rows to 4, making it to not fit on screen. I added a scrollview to the fragment to be able to show all the content when the users have this font size selected.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutHeader1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   ---CONTENT----

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However this isn't showing the whole content  (as it is supposed to). The scroll appears and allows you to read whole text,but the button which is under the text is not shown.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please make it more understandable. What does "font doesnt show content in fragment" mean?

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to a scroll view, otherwise you would have seen a part of your views inside that Fragment, you need to put more code of that fragment maybe we could help you find out the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to set

for `ScrollView`

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

for `LinearLayout`/your container

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

this is proper way to fill `ScrollView` without cutting top/bottom edge, maybe this is your problem (description isn't clear at all...)